# In Magento 2.2.5 The Custom attributes values are not coming in Collection

Tags: product-attribute, custom-attributes, customer-attribute, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5, I am creating a Custom Product and Customer attributes. 
It is saving fine, but while retrieving, It is not coming in the Collection.
Here is my Code.
UpgradeData.php

```
 $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);        
 $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
$eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,'deal_start',['type' => 'varchar','backend' => '','frontend' => '','label' => 'Deal Start Date','input' => 'date','class' => '','source' => '','global' => 1,'visible' => true,'required' => true,'user_defined' => true,'default' => null,'searchable' => false,'filterable' => false,'comparable' => false,'visible_on_front' => false,'used_in_product_listing' => false,'unique' => false,'apply_to' => '','system' => 1,'group' => 'General','option' => array('values' => array(""))]);
$eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,'deal_end',['type' => 'varchar','backend' => '','frontend' => '','label' => 'Deal End Date','input' => 'date','class' => '','source' => '','global' => 1,'visible' => true,'required' => true,'user_defined' => true,'default' => null,'searchable' => false,'filterable' => false,'comparable' => false,'visible_on_front' => false,'used_in_product_listing' => false,'unique' => false,'apply_to' => '','system' => 1,'group' => 'General','option' => array('values' => array(""))]);
$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'merchant_group', ['type' => 'varchar','label' => 'Merchant Group','input' => 'select','source' => 'Apptha\Customergroup\Model\Config\Source\Options','required' => true,'visible' => true,'position' => 333,'system' => true,'backend' => '']);
$attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'merchant_group')->addData(['used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']]);
$attribute->save();
```

Comment: Please specify what you tried to get the custom attribute value in your collection.

Comment: Use config *use_in_list* or add manualy .